# driver.switchTo().alert() not working google chrome and firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to accept alert using `driver.switchTo().alert()` keywords. But its not working for google chrome and Firefox. But its work for IE11. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAMpW.png) Error message print in Eclipse Console.[This is the alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gjsg.png)

**This is my code :**

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

Are there any solution for this error ?

Comment: Can you please share the url for which you are trying ?

Comment: Sorry  Ankur Singh, Its my local URL. I added the popup message in above question.

Comment: Please share the HTML for this alert.

Comment: Unable to catch html for this alert. Because element locators not support after open this alert.

Answer (score 2):

You can wait for the alert to appears then accept it.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
alert.accept();
```

Answer (score 1):

why using two times switching to alert?

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert(); 
String alertMessage= alert.getText(); 
alert.accept();
System.out.println("Alert msg is : "+alertMessage);
```

Comment: Sorry , i edited the question. Please see the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the JavaScript answer. The documentation has examples for all languages.
https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/js_alerts_prompts_and_confirmations/

```
await driver.wait(until.alertIsPresent()); 
el = driver.switchTo().alert();
await el.accept();
```